# Lipschitz function admits Whitney stratification

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, convex-analysis

I've been reading [Topological Aspects of Nonsmooth Optimization](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-1897-9) by Vladimir Shikhman.

There I have found the following observation that:

> Lipschitz functions $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ admit
>   a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ Whitney stratification.

It's not proven anywhere there, and I do not see why this is true.

We would like to partition the graph of $f$ into $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ submanifolds $\{\mathcal{S}_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that 
$$\overline{S_i} \cap S_j \neq \emptyset \implies S_j \subset \overline{S_i} \setminus S_i , \ i \neq j$$

$$\forall x \in \overline{S_i} \cap S_j, \{x_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset S_i : \lim_{k \to \infty}x_k = x,  \lim_{k \to \infty}T_{x_k}S_i = \mathcal{T} \implies T_xS_j \subset \mathcal{T} $$
and for all $i \in I, \ u \in S_i$ there is satisfies the transversality condition: $(0,...,0,1) = e_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $$e_{n+1} \in T_uS_i$$

Now, how can we check that any stratification of the graph of $f$ is Whitney and nonvertical?

For example, for $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ the nonverticality conditoin isn't satisfied, because the vector tangent to the graph in (0,0) is $e_{n+1}$.

It seems that the nonverticality is satisfied for Lipschtz functions, because there is a double cone whose vertex can be translated along the graph, so that the graph always remains entirely outside the cone.

But I don't know how to make that argument precise.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: I think this is in Whitney's book:    Whitney, H. (1957), Geometric Integration Theory, Princeton Mathematical Series, 21, Princeton, NJ and London: Princeton University Press and Oxford University Press, pp. XV+387, MR 0087148, Zbl 0083.28204.

Comment: @BenMcKay Thank you. I've been looking for this fact in the book, but I haven't found it yet. There is a whole chapter dedicated to Lipschitz functions. I'll keep looking, though. Thanks.

Comment: The conditions you wrote on the submanifolds don't make any sense to me. The first asks that $S_j \subset \overline{S_i}\setminus S_j$ ? The third appears to ask that $e_{n+1} \notin \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$...

Answer (score 7):

In general **no such stratification exists**. Lipschitz functions coincide with $C^1$ functions on sets of positive measure:

> **Theorem.** *If $f$ is Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that the Lebesgue
>   measure of the set  $\{ f\neq g\}$ is less than $\epsilon$.*

You can find a proof of this result in almost any book on geometric measure theory, see for example Theorem 1 in Section 6.6.1 in

**L. C. Evans, R. F. Gariepy,** *Measure theory and fine properties of functions*. Studies in Advanced Mathematics. CRC Press, Boca Raton, FL, 1992.

Therefore, you can decompose the graph of $f$ into countably many $C^1$ pieces (defined on measurable sets) and a set of measure zero.  However, in general a Lipschitz function need not coincide with a $C^2$ function on a set of positive measure so there is no hope for any sort of $C^2$ stratification even for functions defined on a real line.

By the way, I checked the book by  Vladimir Shikhman and there is no such result as the one formulated in the question. Instead, they *consider Lipschitz functions $f : \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ whose graphs admit a $C^\infty$-
Whitney stratification*, and that is a different story. No theorem, but assumption.